# How do I do logging.exception() on exceptions gathered by asyncio.gather()?

Tags: python, logging, python-asyncio

I greatly enjoy the information returned by `logging.exception()`, however this function can only be used in an exception handler.

Now, running `asyncio.gather(..., return_exceptions=True)` does not raise exceptions; rather, the exceptions are returned as `Exception` objects.

I would like to log these `Exceptions` objects with the same details as with `logging.exception()`, but since I'm not in an exception handler, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the exception instances returned by `gather` and pass them as `exc_info` like

```py
results = asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)
for exc in [r for r in results if isinstance(r, BaseException)]
    logger.debug("message", exc_info=exc)
```

This should give the same output as `logger.exception("message")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate results returned by gather and log errors with exc_info

```
results = await asyncio.gather(*batch, return_exceptions=True)
for res in results:
    if isinstance(res, BaseException):
        logger.exception('Task exception', exc_info=res)
```

Answer (score -1):

> 

```
results = asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)
for exc  in [r.exception() for r in results]:
    if r:
        logger.error("message", exc_info=True)
```